# How to get a list from comma seperated data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I want to use an sql like this:

```
select * from product 
 where productId IN (select RelatedProductIds 
                       FROM product 
                      where productID = 11)
```

`RelatedProductIds` contains `'2286,11212,11031,11212,11212,4082,9339,9214'`

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Is it too late to change the design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN Product b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.productId, b.RelatedProductIds) > 0
WHERE   b.productID = 11
```

As an advice, you should properly normalize the table. Saving comma separated value in a column is a bad design.

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: I know it is a bad desing I will change it when I have a time:) Thanks for your answer.